# How to represent a Knockout Competition graph on mobile?

Tags: mobile, graphs

For our platform we would love to have a good way to visualize a knockout system. So you can easily follow that from quarter final X the winner goes to semi final Y.

A simple diagram like below does wonders to understand a schedule like this.

The problem is; lack of space on mobile.

**What are some good user interfaces with similar graph-like structures that work good on mobile?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the most suitable way is to fit each of the columns you present in a screen, scrollable if necessary, and a button to navigate to the next/previous screen:

```
Round of 16
---
20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

..Scrollable..

Quarter Finals >
```

.

```
Quarter Finals
---
20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

< Round of 16 | Semi Finals >
```

.

```
Semi Finals
---
20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

< Quarter Finals | Final >
```

.

```
Final
---
20 June - Place
Team A
Team B

< Semi Finals
```